# How to store msgbox value to access database in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to store the "status" to the access when i click Yes, but when i click yes it shows this error message.

**

You cannot add or change a record because a related record is
    required in table 'Userss'.>>

**

```
    Private Sub btnContactOwner_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnContactOwner.Click

    If MsgBox("Are you sure want to confirm this room?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirmation") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        status = "Non-Available"
    Else
        status = "Available"



    End If
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\room.accdb")
    con.Open()
    sql = "Insert into room(status)values('" & status & " ')"
    objcmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: sounds like your 'room' table has a foreign key column to your users table? Can you post the full details about your tables?

Comment: Agreeing with @5uperdan.  Taking a guess that it has a room number that needs to be inserted with it?  Or updating a room that is already there?

Comment: @5uperdan
I have foreign key between room table and my user table, here I attached with the link of screenshot

http://oi60.tinypic.com/vn19ir.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a row in your Room table and you're only specifying a value for the status column.
Your Room table has a column 'StudentID' which has a foreign key constraint to the table 'Userss'. To create a row in your room table you will need to also specify a value for the 'StudentID' column.

```
sql = "Insert into room(status,studentID) values('" & status & "'," & studentID & ")"
```

where studentID is a valid integer from your Userss table

You may also want to look at [parameterised queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and/or the string.Format method:

```
sql = String.Format("Insert into room(status,studentID) values('{0}',{1})", status, studentID)
```